# Convert days to get hours, minutes and seconds of two dates using momentjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, momentjs

How to convert days to get the hours, minutes and seconds using momentjs? I think my calculation is wrong because I'm getting the difference of date today and date that I'm getting from the API which has 5days.

So far this is my code

```
const countdown = () => {
  let dueDate = '2019-12-04 12:50:42 AM'; //getting this value from the API

  let eventTime = moment(dateDue).unix();
  let currentTime = moment(new Date()).unix();
  let diffTime = eventTime - currentTime;

   const interval = 1000;
   let duration = moment.duration(diffTime * interval, 'milliseconds');
   duration = moment.duration(duration - interval, 'milliseconds');

   countDowntimer[dateDue] = setInterval(() => {
     setMinutes(duration.minutes());
     setSeconds(duration.seconds());
   }, interval);

   return `${duration.hours()}hr ${duration.minutes()}m ${duration.seconds()}s`;

 };

 const timer = countdown(minutes, seconds);

 return timer;
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all NEVER subtract from the final date while making a countdown timer, instead calculate the difference at each iteration.
Then for calculate each duration you need to take as value the integer part of the duration and then with the decimal part calculate the next interval multiplied by X ( where x are seconds to make a minute, minute to make an hour and so on).

```js
const time = document.getElementById("time");

const countdown = () => {
  let dueDate = '2019-12-04 12:50:42 AM'; //getting this value from the API

  let eventTime = moment(dueDate, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss a');
  const interval = 1000;
  setInterval(() => {
    const hours = moment.duration(eventTime - moment()).asHours();
    const hInt = Math.floor(hours);
    const minutes = moment.duration(60 * (hours - hInt), 'minutes').asMinutes();
    const mInt = Math.floor(minutes);
    const seconds = moment.duration(60 * (minutes - mInt), 'seconds').asSeconds();
    const sInt = Math.floor(seconds);
    time.innerHTML = `${hInt}hr ${mInt}m ${sInt}s`;
    // set react state here
  }, interval);
};

countdown();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment.min.js"></script>
<span id="time"></span>
```

Comment: Did you compare the currentTime here? or get the difference?

Comment: moment() gives you the current time so eventTime - moment() gives you the difference

Answer (score 0):

Using [moment-duration-format](https://github.com/jsmreese/moment-duration-format)

```js
const countdown = () => {
  let dueDate = '2019-12-04 12:50:42 AM';
  let end = moment(dueDate, 'YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss A');
  let start = moment();

  const interval = 1000;
  setInterval(() => {
    start = moment()
    let diff = end.diff(start)
    document.body.innerHTML = moment.duration(diff).format("HH[hr] mm[m] ss[s]");
  }, interval);

}
countdown()
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment.js" integrity="sha256-H9jAz//QLkDOy/nzE9G4aYijQtkLt9FvGmdUTwBk6gs=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment-duration-format/2.3.2/moment-duration-format.min.js" integrity="sha256-M2KULKSJyw+G0068JiMlM9GX4XpLdUButSzBqntKDZM=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```